# Include ControlsFX in Scene Builder?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, controlsfx

Is it possible to include the component of [Controls FX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) in [Scene Builder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/sb2download-2177776.html) ?

If yes, can you tell me how, if no can you tell me if there're alternatives ?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes you can. But unfortunately **all** ControlsFX controls are not supported by scene builder. An issue titled, ["All controls should be supported by SceneBuilder"](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issue/243/all-controls-should-be-supported-by) is currently opened with the ControlsFX team.

### Update

Since [SceneBuilder 8.2.0](http://gluonhq.com/scene-builder-8-2-0-now/) you can directly search for an artifact from SceneBuilder and include them using the brand new Library Manager \o/

To open the Library Manager:

- Click the down arrow to the right of Library and choose import JAR/FXML File.

[image]

- This will open up the Library Manager Dialog:

[image]

- Select "Search Repository" and type in "ControlsFX" and click the Search button.

[image]

- This will display all the controlsfx artifacts listed in the repositories that is added by default. Choose "org.controlsfx:controlsfx" and click on "Add Jar".

[image]

- It then displays Dialog in which you can select the components that you want to import. Select them and press the "Import Component" button.

[image]

- All the selected components are loaded into the SceneBuilder.

[image]

---

### Import controls to SceneBuilder before 8.2.0

Prior to SceneBuilder 8.2.0, you can manually import the controls:

- click the down arrow to the right of `Library`
- choose "Import JAR/FXML File"
- select the [`controlsfx jar`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx).

[image]

Comment: Any good way to do this with a gradle project? Just download another copy of the jar and import it manually?

Comment: What has gradle project to do with SceneBuilder?

Comment: The gradle dependency jar isn't really held anywhere within the project file so you can't access it to import it.

Comment: Is it possible to have actual icons instead of question marks for custom components?

Comment: @MWin123 It can be done via the SBKit. I am not sure if there is an API to achieve the same. Feel free to log an issue in the [Scene Builder repository](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Maven then just link it directly from your local repository rather than having to manage a separate instance.

the default setup in linux environments is ~/.m2/repository/org/controlsfx/

You'll have to remember to update it manually if you update.

Comment: This is on point. The package used in project and Scene Builder must match as a new widget update might arrive.