# I want to use BrowserView class of Jx browser in FXML in a JavaFX application

Tags: javafx, fxml

I want to create a browser using JavaFX and FXML for this i want to use the libraries of Jx Browser(an open source browser) rather than the JavaFX WebView.
Is there any way that i can add the BrowserView of Jx Browser to my FXML?

Comment: Are you talking about [JXBrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser)? I couldn't find any links to JFXBrowser, it would be helpful if you could put the source links for JFXBrowser.

Comment: my bad it's jxbrowser

Comment: In that case, let me inform you that JXBrowser is not Open Source. You can however get a free license if you are doing an open source or academic project.

Comment: In case JXBrowser comes with a jar and you use SceneBuilder to create your FXMLs, you can import the custom control by adding the jar in SceneBuilder. For more information. have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29602003/1759128).

Comment: I not being able to add the jar in SceneBuilder following the post.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: i've added the jar but i cant find  BrowserView to insert it in the fxml